# Child DAC are not inserting when add a new Item

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have 2 scenarios, I am facing issue.

1. I have 3 DAC, One is Parent and other 2 are child DAC.
2. I have tab view, and showing data accordingly.
   First tab showing Parent DAC data.
   Second and third are showing child DAC data.

I am creating new item, Now i press Add(+) button and fill, Information in Parent tab, but not filled any data in 2nd and 3rd tab, when i press SAVE then only parent DAC saved, 2nd and 3rd tab rows not created in database, I want to save 2nd and 3rd Tab DAC also, what should i do?

Another case:
i am not allowing DAC to update, I am setting DAC.Cahce.AllowUpdated = false; all controls are disabled  excepting Checkbox, why?

Also when we are on 3rd tab and click on toolbar Navigation button, then 1st tab data doesn't refresh, it is showing previous selected item data. How to fix this issue?

We are not using PXGrid for any child data, there is one to one relation ship between all 3 DAC.

```
    /// Parent View
    public SelectFrom<Parent>.View parentTran;
 
   /// Child view
   public SelectFrom<Child>      .Where<Child.tranId.IsEqual<Parent.nCTranId.AsOptional>>.View
           childAnalysis;


    
    #region TranId

    // Child DAC Field.
    public abstract class tranId:PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<tranId> {
    }

    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(Parent.nCTranId))]
    [PXParent(typeof(Select<Parent, Where<Parent.nCTranId, Equal<Current<tranId>>>>))]
    public virtual int? TranId {
        get; set;
    }
    #endregion
```

Comment: Please show your DAC's including at least the fields of each DAC that are used to define the parent/child relationship.  Also, please show how you defined your views in the graph.  The most likely issue is that you may not have the relationships defined properly, but I cannot give any specific help without seeing your code.  Also, I'd recommend reviewing the T210 course on Acumatica Open University (https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t210-development-customized-forms-and-master-detail-relationship/).

Comment: I have updated a code with relation view as well as specify child dac field.

Comment: In a parent/child relationship, I don't believe it is "legal" to make the tranID of the child AsOptional.  Also, you noted that you are not using a grid for your child DAC.  Insertion into the grid would naturally connect it to the parent, but lack of a grid means you will have to code the creation of the child DAC if you want it to exist.  If the data is 1:1 with the parent, I would expect to simply create a DAC extension and place all fields in the DAC extension, but you may have other purposes.  Otherwise, I don't see any issues with parent/child at first glance.

Comment: Here is a sample of parent/child (using BQL, but you can do in FBQL if you prefer).  Notice how the child refers to the parent via Current<> (or .FromCurrent in FBQL).
Parent view: public PXSelect<INRegister, Where<INRegister.docType, Equal<INDocType.adjustment>>> adjustment;
Child view: public PXSelect<INTran, Where<INTran.docType, Equal<Current<INRegister.docType>>, And<INTran.refNbr, Equal<Current<INRegister.refNbr>>>>> transactions;

Comment: i did same as you suggested, But still child DAC not initializing when press Add Button, As i mention i am not using Grid for child DAC, All child DAC fields in FormView(inside a tab). what should i do to Initialize DAC also when press Add?

If i do not create child instance then fields are not initializing and showing previous dac data?

Comment: You are correct about the child DAC not initializing automatically.  When you think about it, even if you have a grid for the child view, you still have to add the child via the + button.  However, there is a section of one of the training guides regarding creating a child DAC record when you create the parent.  (I think it was a default warranty in the sample.)  I'll dig up exactly where and try to post an answer for you regarding initializing a "Default" child record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at T210 regarding Master-Detail Relationships.  It contains a section on inserting a default record, which sounds like what you are trying to do with your child DAC.  The training can be found at https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/development/t210-development-customized-forms-and-master-detail-relationship/ on the Acumatica website.  Specifically look at pages 103 and 104.

In step 3 of the section,  you will see use of the RowInserted event to insert the child record.  Since the RowInserted event fires only when creating a record, making it safe to insert the child record.

See the following code sample. I tried to use as much of your sample as possible, but I merged it with the technique shown in the training guide.  Disclaimer: It will compile, but I have not built the prerequisites to fully test the code.

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.BQL.Fluent;

namespace SSCS.CodeSample
{
    public class CodeSampleEntry : PXGraph<CodeSampleEntry, DACParent>
    {
        #region Data Views
        /// Parent View
        [PXViewName("Parent View - Primary")]
        public SelectFrom<DACParent>.View ParentTran;

        /// Child view
        [PXViewName("Child View")]
        public SelectFrom<DACChild>
            .Where<DACChild.tranId.IsEqual<DACParent.nCTranId.FromCurrent>>
            .View ChildAnalysis;
        #endregion

        // RowInserted Event to Create a Default Child Record
        // See T210 Master-Detail training guide from Acumatica
        protected virtual void _(Events.RowInserted<DACParent> e)
        {
            // Ensure there isn't a child record already
            if (ChildAnalysis.Select().Count == 0)
            {
                // Save state of IsDirty so that we can restore it
                // after inserting the default child record
                // so that we don't force the user to save
                // unless they actually enter data somewhere
                bool oldDirty = ChildAnalysis.Cache.IsDirty;

                // Create an object for the child
                // and fill in any data that should be
                // populated by default
                DACChild newChild = new DACChild();
                newChild.MyData = "My Value";

                // Insert the new child record into the cache
                ChildAnalysis.Insert(newChild);

                // Restore the IsDirty flag
                // The insert above will have marked the view as
                // dirty.  If it wasn't dirty before, it should be
                // treated as if it still isn't
                ChildAnalysis.Cache.IsDirty = oldDirty;
            }
        }

    }

    [PXCacheName("Parent DAC")]
    public class DACParent : IBqlTable
    {
        #region NCTranId
        [PXDBIdentity]
        public virtual int? NCTranId { get; set; }
        public abstract class nCTranId
            : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<nCTranId> { }
        #endregion
    }

    [PXCacheName("Child DAC")]
    public class DACChild : IBqlTable
    {
        #region TranId
        [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
        [PXDBDefault(typeof(DACParent.nCTranId))]
        [PXParent(typeof(SelectFrom<DACParent>
            .Where<DACParent.nCTranId.IsEqual<DACChild.tranId.FromCurrent>>))]
        public virtual int? TranId { get; set; }
        public abstract class tranId
            : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<tranId> { }
        #endregion

        #region MyData
        [PXDBString()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "My Data Field")]
        public virtual string MyData { get; set; }
        public abstract class myData
            : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<myData> { }
        #endregion
    }
}
```